# How do I append plain arguments and flag arguments into a single array using argparse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I want to do something like the following:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Strings and ints in one array')
parser.add_argument('values', metavar='STRING', nargs='*',
                    action='append', help='Strings')
parser.add_argument('-i', '--int', dest='values', type=int,
                    action='append', help='Ints')
```

Such that running the program with `prog 1 -i2 3 -i4 5` will produce `["1", 2, "3", 4, "5"]`.

If I don't put the arguments in the same destination variable, then I will have no way of knowing the correct order of the arguments. But when I try to use the same destination variable, I run into the problem that using `nargs='*'` produces `[["1", "3", "5"], 2, 4]`, while using `nargs='?'` works, but limits me to only one plain argument.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Why not just flatten the list?

Comment: 'append' action does not make sense for positional arguments.

Comment: @lane: Because the order of the arguments would not be recoverable, just like if I had used separate destination variables.

Comment: @hpaulj: What is the correct way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score -1):

```
In [110]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Strings and ints in one
     ...:  array')
     ...: parser.add_argument('values', metavar='STRING', nargs='*',
     ...:                     action='append', help='Strings')
     ...: parser.add_argument('-i', '--int', dest='values', type=int,
     ...:                     action='append', help='Ints');

In [111]: parser.parse_args('1 -i2 3 -i4 5'.split())
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-i VALUES] [STRING [STRING ...]]
ipython3: error: unrecognized arguments: 3 5
```

The `values` positional gets used only once.  Thus there's nothing to handle the '3' and '5'.  `append` action does not make sense with a positional.

There is a `intermixed` mode (I'm the author of that), than can treat the '3' and '5' as part of the `nargs='*'`:

```
In [112]: parser.parse_intermixed_args('1 -i2 3 -i4 5'.split())
Out[112]: Namespace(values=[2, 4, ['1', '3', '5']])
```

Your use of a common `dest` confused me for at bit.  In this mode, it parses all the flagged strings, and then handles the remaining ones with the `positional` action.

Make both flagged arguments:

```
In [118]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Strings and ints in one
     ...:  array')
     ...: parser.add_argument('-v', metavar='STRING',
     ...:                     action='append', help='Strings')
     ...: parser.add_argument('-i', '--int',  type=int,
     ...:                     action='append', help='Ints');
In [119]: parser.parse_args('-v1 -i2 -v3 -i4 -v5'.split())
Out[119]: Namespace(int=[2, 4], v=['1', '3', '5'])
```

Now use the same `dest`:

```
In [120]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Strings and ints in one
     ...:  array')
     ...: parser.add_argument('-v', metavar='STRING', dest='values',
     ...:                     action='append', help='Strings')
     ...: parser.add_argument('-i', '--int',  type=int,dest='values',
     ...:                     action='append', help='Ints');
In [121]: parser.parse_args('-v1 -i2 -v3 -i4 -v5'.split())
Out[121]: Namespace(values=['1', 2, '3', 4, '5'])
```

That's what you want, right?  But for a slightly different input.

Because of how it parses the inputs, `argparse` does not preserve order very well.  Work with the `sys.argv` directly if  you don't like what it's doing.

Comment: Yes, I realize that I could use a flagged argument for both, but that isn't what I want to do in terms of the interface for the program. I do want to have all the features and benefits of argparse, because of how flexibly it handles the flag names, and also because there are other flags that I am using the normal way. But it seems you are saying there is no way to achieve what I want using argparse?

Comment: Think logically.  Each positional action can only be used once.  A flagged action can be used once for each flag.  Traditionally parsers handled a bunch of options/flags, followed by positionals - as the usage displays.  `argparse` actually lets you mix them, but you can't define a variable number of positionals.

Comment: You can define a variable number of positionals. That's what `nargs='*'` does, for example. There is nothing inherently logically inconsistent about interleaving them in the way I intend. What I'm gathering from you is that the problem is that the argparse _implementation_ does not support this.

Comment: '*' accepts multiple values for one defined action.  They have to occur together (except for the `intermixed` usage that I demonstrate).  They could also be returned as `extras` to `parse_known_args`.  But for interleaved, inorder values, you are on your own.  Think also about how you'll explain this usage to your users (or yourself 6 months from now). For many the help and error checking are as important as the parsing itself.

Comment: But what really is the goal here?  Using `argparse` to handle a mix of flagged and positional arguments, or to convert some strings to `int` while leaving others as strings?  Does '-i' have to be the int marker?  How about parsing '1 i2 3 i4 5'? or 'b1 2 b3 4 b5'?

Comment: `argparse` iterates through the `sys.argv` list, first looking for positional match (based on `nargs`), and then processing the next flagged argument(s), and so on.  Each `action` assigns or appends values to its `dest`.  Flagged `actions` are handled each time the flag appears; positionals are handled in the defined order (like a one-time calendar entry).

Comment: The usage is not so hard to describe. This program essentially processes text in order, and the text may be supplied either as the argument itself or as a filename that contains the text. I want to use `-f` to tag the filenames, but leave the literal arguments without a tage to keep the majority use-case cleaner. For example, `prog foo -f bar baz` should process the string "foo", the contents of the file "bar", and the string "baz", in that order. This interface is not hard to describe. And yes, I recognize that help and error checking are important, that's why I want this to work in argparse.

Comment: By `usage` I meant the line in the help labeled as 'usage'.  The 'description/epilog' parts can be essay length.

Comment: How about omitting these two Actions from the parser, and use `parse_known_args`.  These values will then appear in the extras, which you can parse in your own way.  Use `argparse` for the stuff it's designed to do;  Handling [foo -f bar baz] doesn't need its help.